# ffmpeg av_register_all() not working?

Tags: ios, ffmpeg

I'm attempting to use ffmpeg on iOS. When I call av_register_all() then attempt to open the file using avformat_open_input() I get the following error:

```
No URL Protocols are registered. Missing call to av_register_all()?
```

Has anyone seen this before? Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had protocols disabled in the build script in which I built the static library.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to see the ffmpeg list of available protocols type:

```
./configure --list-protocols
```

and you will have something like that

```
applehttp       https           rtmps
cache           md5         rtmpt
concat          mmsh            rtmpte
crypto          mmst            rtp
file            pipe            tcp
gopher          rtmp            tls
http            rtmpe           udp
httpproxy
```

if you have disable everything in you ffmpeg configuration, usually in this case it is enough to enable the file protocol:

```
./configure \
...
    --enable-protocol=file \
...
```